# Can someone explain Mahabharat Anushasan parva chapter 44 verse 14? It seems very out of place and inappropriate

Tags: bhishma, mahabharata

[image: chapter 44 verse 14]
Mahabharat anushasan parva chapter 44 verse 14

Comment: Kanya marriage at these ages is found in all Hindu scriptures. Check the other questions on the site for clarification.

Comment: Please don't confuse marriage with consummation of marriage